# jQuery validation in a separate file .js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML file with a contact form. I want a jQuery validation for this form, but in other file, with .js extension. JQuery validates the form when it is written in the HTML file. But if I transcribe it for .js, it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pt-br" lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Escola Desafio - Contato</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script language="javaScript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
        <script language="javaScript" src="js/scripts1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
            $(window).load(function(){
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#frmContato').validate({ // initialize the plugin
                        rules: {
                            nome: {
                                required: true
                            },
                            field2: {
                                required: true
                            }
                        },
                        errorPlacement: function(){
                            return false;
                        },
                        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
                            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
                            return false; // for demo
                        }
                    });
                });
            });//]]> 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<form id="frmContato" method="post" name="frmContato">
                    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" title="Insira o nome completo" placeholder="Nome Completo" onkeyup="AllowAlphabet()"/> 
                        <select name="assunto" id="assunto" title="Escolha um assunto" class="select">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Selecione um assunto</option>
                            <option value="duvidas">Dúvidas/Informações</option>
                            <option value="falha">Falha/Erro/Indisponibilidade</option>
                            <option value="lentidao">Lentidão</option>
                            <option value="liberacao">Liberação/Bloqueio de Senha</option>
                            <option value="reclamacao">Reclamações/Críticas</option>
                            <option value="sugestao">Sugestões/Elogios</option>
                        </select> 
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" title="Insira o seu e-mail" placeholder="E-mail" />
                    <textarea placeholder="Escreva a sua mensagem aqui" rows="4" cols="50" class="textarea"></textarea>
                    <input id="btnEnviar" type="submit" value="Enviar" class="inline" onsubmit="return validateForm()"/>
                </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my .js:

```
 window.onload = function(){
        $('#nome').keypress(function(e) {
            var keyCode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which); // Variar a chamada do keyCode de acordo com o ambiente.
                if (keyCode > 47 && keyCode < 58) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
        });
};
```

I tried to do so :

```
window.onload = function(){
    //alert("teste");
    //alert("teste");

    $('#nome').keypress(function(e) {
        var keyCode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which); // Variar a chamada do keyCode de acordo com o ambiente.
            if (keyCode > 47 && keyCode < 58) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
    });
};

window.load = function(){
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#frmContato').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            rules: {
                nome: {
                    required: true
                },
                field2: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function(){
                return false;
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
                alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
                    return false; // for demo
                }
            });
        });
    });  
};
```

Comment: I'm guessing your scripts.js and scripts1.js are your attempts? In that case you need to include them in the dom AFTER jQuery. By doing this, you don't need the window.onload part as well. `$(document).ready()` does this for you.

Comment: Bjorn Sorensen, I did as you said. Now it' is working in Firefox. Thank you :)

Comment: You can't have more than one `window.onload` function. Every time you assign this, it replaces the previous one, and only the last one will be used.

Comment: Is `window.load` a typo for `window.onload`?

Comment: Why don't you do everything in `$(document).ready()`? You can do this as many times as you want. You can also use `window.addEventListener("load", ...)` or `$(window).load(...)` multiple times, they add to each other instead of replacing.

Comment: Barmar, Oh, yes, I understood. Indeed, it is easier to use $(document).ready(). Thank you :)